# Visual Studio 2008 - re-prompt to migrate web app from .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, migration

If you have already been prompted to migrate your solution from .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5 and you responded "No" at the time, how do you get Visual Studio 2008 to re-prompt you with this question?

Sorry, if there is a real simple solution to this one.

Comment: Anybody know where the fact that it prompted you is stored? maybe this value can be cleared which would would allow you to shutdown a solution and re-open it to get prompted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to get VS to do it for you. You can go to each project in your solution and set the 'Target Framework' on the 'Application' page of project properties.

Comment: I did that. But does this update the references though? I keep getting some error that it kind find System.Linq on my using System.Linq; line.

Comment: I just did it last week. It updated a few references, but not all. I do not use linq, so I don't know about that, but I do know that it did not update System.Web.Extensions in all my projects.

Comment: @tyndall What version of Linq are you using? Also, you could always add a reference to System.Linq manually...

Comment: All I saw was a assembly System.Data.Linq.dll. Isn't System.Linq in System.Core.dll except my app is using the wrong one. Its using the core from 2.0